# Continuous monotone function and fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Supose $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is continuous and monotonic. Then for every $x\in [0,1]$, x is a fixed point or the sequence $(f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f )(x) (n~times)$ converges to a fixed point of $f$.

Is this true if we assume that $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: If $f(x)=1-x$ and $x\ne \frac12$, then $f^{\circ n}(x)$ does not converge to a fixed point of $f$